# Scroll Position Bottom

Tags: jquery

I want to calculate the Window Scroll Position of **Bottom**. And want to see the result on Top-Right corner of window. for this purpose My code is like bellow:

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
      var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
      var windowScrollPosTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
      var windowScrollPosBottom = windowHeight + windowScrollPosTop;
      
      var objectOffset = jQuery(".example-photo").offset();
      var objectOffsetTop = objectOffset.top;
      
      jQuery(".status").html(objectOffsetTop);
       
     });
    });
```

```css
 .status{
    background: #FFF;
    color: #000;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 900;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="status"></div>
    
    <div class="container">
     <p>Paragraphp</p>
     <img class="example-photo" src="location/image.jpg" alt="demo" />
    </div>
    <body>
```

**Problem:** When I am resizing the browser size, the scrolling position is not changing. I think that it should be change when shrinking or increasing the browser size. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with: " Window Scroll Position of Bottom" Bottom of what? Then your js code, all the `window*` variables are never used. You actually only use the objectOffsetTop.. why? So even someone scrolls the value will never change.. Here is a fiddle of your code:  https://jsfiddle.net/cv1ezrog/

Comment: wrap the code `jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ ....` in a `$(window).on('resize', function(){ /*my code block*/  });`

Comment: Why do you think the vertical offset of the image should change when you resize the window?

Comment: Resizing the browser does not trigger scroll event, you should use `$(window).on('scroll resize', function{ ... })` instead.

Comment: Bottom of the class ".example-photo"